# Standalone mounting utilty for Windows Server 2003 x64?

Tags: mount, iso-image, windows-server-2003

I am in need of a mounting utility that can mount ISO images virtually to a machine that is a standalone application without an installation.

I know of Magic Disc and Daemon tools but they both require installations. Microsoft doesn't currently offer such a utility so I was wondering if anyone here knew of one.

Comment: I doubt it exists. Virtual CD drives usually have to install a driver to simulate the drive and install an application to specify which image to mount.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. If Windows offered API's for it and natively supported it like every other operating system, I would bet that there would be a lot more applications that do this. Thanks for your input.

Comment: There has been a small tool written by Microsoft itself. CF http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/620/xp_small_free_way_to_use_and_mount_images_iso_files_without_burning_them/ Unfortunately it only works under *x86* OSes. If we could get the source code, we could maybe compile an x64 version, but I doubt whether anyone has got this code either.

Comment: While it’s true that such programs must use a driver to pull it off, that doesn’t mean they have to permanently install one. There are plenty of programs that **temporarily** install a driver, then uninstall it when they exit. To get access to low-level system components, several Sysinternals tools extract and install a driver when started and remove them on exit. Also, the 360KB program [DriveSnapshot](http://www.drivesnapshot.de/en/view.htm) lets you mount a drive-image without having to install anything (it’s portable). Sadly it doesn’t support `.iso` files, but you could try requesting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No viable solution is available at this time. Windows does not natively support mounting without a third-party driver/software.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is 3 years old question but in case anybody came here, You can now use this portable utility:

[WinCEEmu portable](http://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/portable/)

I have used it on Win 7 x64 and it's OK.
It also works on Win Server 2K3.